# Integrating Laravel Echo with React/Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, laravel-echo

How would I go about connecting my Laravel Echo server with my React/Redux application? I currently have setup basic React/Redux app and I want to integrate Laravel Echo inside of it. I created `echo.js` helper file:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import authHeader from './auth-header';

export const Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://localhost:9000',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            authHeader();
        }
    }
});
```

And my store looks like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from '../_reducers';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware
    )
);
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @dacastro4 No, I didn't

Comment: One of the things that I did, was passing another parameters in the constructor object called `client` and passed the socket.io instance